# sum of squares of max 2 of 3 SICP exercise

Tags: scheme

I have written a procedure to compute the sum of squares of the first and second greatest of 3 numbers as below...

```
    (define (max2of3 x y z)
      (let ((first (max x y))
            (second (max first z)))
        (+ (* first first) (* second second))))
```

But I am getting an error when i execute it...

[2] (load "max2of3")
OK
[3] (max2of3 1 2 3)

[VM ERROR encountered!] Variable not defined in lexical environment
FIRST

While i do understand the error is caused because the interpreter doesn't recognize the variable 'FIRST', i fail to understand why?

By definition from SICP:

The first part of the let expression is a list of name-expression pairs. When the let is evaluated, each
name is associated with the value of the corresponding expression. The body of the let is evaluated with
these names bound as local variables

Doesnt that mean 'let' construct declares a variable in the declaration block?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that why evaluating `(second (max first z)))` `first` is not in scope.

As the definition says, that name is available only in the body of `let`. At this point, the runtime tries to resolve the name in the outer scope, where it's not defined, hence the error.

Note: a nested `let` would solve this problem.

Comment: yup, i jumped the gun..should of read the next paragraph in the text 

"The variables' values are computed outside the let. This matters when the expressions that
provide the values for the local variables depend upon variables having the same names as the
local variables themselves"

Comment: Seasoned Schemers/Lispers would use `let*` instead of nested `let`s. (`let*` is a macro that just expands to nested `let`s.)

Comment: ok, i used the let* construct:

`(define (max2of3 x y z)
  (let* ((first (max x y)) 
         (second (max first z))) 
    (+ (* first first) (* second second))))`
 
But it gives me a result 50 when i call (max2of3 3 5 2)? Its evaluating to (+ 25 25) somehow..

Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: if you are ever unsure, just substitute, you'll see ;)